# java awt WritableRaster and ColorModel equivalent for JavaFX

Tags: java, html, canvas, javafx

Examine the following code:

```
        int[] pixels = new int[] { ... my pixels };
        DataBufferInt databufferint = new DataBufferInt(pixels, pixels.length);
        DirectColorModel directcolormodel = new DirectColorModel(32, 16711680, 65280, 255);
        WritableRaster writableraster = Raster.createWritableRaster(directcolormodel.createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height), databufferint, null);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(directcolormodel, writableraster, false, new Hashtable());
```

I am trying to draw this image on a JavaFX canvas, I use this workaround to accomplish this:

```
graphics.drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null), x, y);
```

But I was thinking, is there any WritableRaster and ColorModel equivalent for JavaFX?

I also have a second question. How would I use the above code to draw an image in a HTML5 canvas using the WritableRaster and ColorModel? I know how to draw pixels on a canvas, I just need to know how I would apply Java's WritableRaster and ColorModel on it.